# Is it safe to share hashed password on github for my hobby project?

Tags: php, mysql, github, passwords

I have created a simple website with native PHP. I have implemented auth feature in it.

I have inserted 1 user into DB . Username and password is admin - admin .

I have hashed the password with built in password_hash() .

I generate it with built-in PHP function :

`password_hash( "admin", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Every time I read about github, they write, that it is not safe to upload the db into github. But I would like to upload at least 1 username and password, because if someone wanna try my project, then he/she does not need to create account, instead he/she could login with admin/admin.
Is it safe to export the mysql db and upload the db to github, which contains only the admin username/pw ?

So there would be a line in my exported sql file, which I would like to upload to github :

`INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "user", "pw") VALUES (1, "admin", "$2y$10$.......");`

Extra question : As I have seen the password_hash() generates every time different hashed strings.
Why generates always different?

Comment: If you have two different questions, then please split them accordingly.

Comment: Note that while GitHub is (very, very slightly) relevant, Git isn't: Git doesn't do passwords, it just stores commits that in turn store files. The *visibility* of these commits, and thus the files, is up to GitHub, not Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's "safe" or not depends on the context.

Default accounts and passwords are a regular way that systems are attacked.  It's better to force your users to create an account on first run than it is to have a default account in place that they may not even know about.  Therefore, the "safe" option is to not have to store the account password at all.

Whether you use GitHub or not isn't relevant.

> Extra question : As I have seen the password_hash() generates every time different hashed strings. Why generates always different?

The [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function does more than just hashing.  It also handles adding salt.  Since the salt is random, you'll get a different result each time.

Comment: I understand you Brad, but I developed it for a really simple project which I wanna upload to github, not for going live on a server. The DB has only this 1 user and blog posts. In this case is it still unsafe? Should I remove it from db and upload it without users? So the uploaded db should only have other informations, for example blog post? Thank you.

Comment: @John That's for you to decide.  If it were me... no, I'd do it right.  There are decades of examples where people have made some "really simple project" and then it was copied and grew and grew until it's now a piece in a complicated large project, and now there's a security hole.